# How to set an automatic BufferSize?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, networking, buffer

I'm using the `Socket.BeginReceive` method in order to receive data from connected clients. However, the messages I send may vary too much in size. For example, one message may be 100,000 bytes in size and the other may be 3 bytes in size, and the 100,000 bytes message is rarely sent! Is there a way of setting the`BufferSize` value to an automatic value just like the usage of `Socket.Receive`?

Comment: You misunderstand how sockets work, be sure to read up on the basics.  You'll never get 100,000 bytes with a single call.  UDP can only transfer a message that is no bigger than the MTU.  TCP is incapable of handling messages, it implements a stream.  Using a 4096 byte buffer is a fine choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your buffer size to maximum unit transmission (MTU) size of IP packet (64 KB). It never exceeds that size because larger messages are fragmented so they could be transmitted easier.